# How to get/refer a user id in Django dynamically?

Tags: python, django

I have a questionnaire page that works fine. I like to get a feedback to a page about which the user has filled out the questionnaires. I can make it manually if I add the `user_name_id` but I don't know how to get it dynamically.

**views.py**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def index(request):
    viselkedestipus = Viselkedestipus.objects.all()   //this generats me the list of the users
    stressz_teszt = Stressz_teszt.objects.filter(user_name_id=???)   //this is where I need a solution

template = loader.get_template('stressz/index.html')

context = {
    'viselkedestipus': viselkedestipus,
    'stressz_teszt': stressz_teszt,
    }
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**html**

```
{% for item in viselkedestipus %}
<div class="card my-2">
    <div class="card-header h3">
        {{ item.user_name }}
    </div>
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="card-header">User: {{ item.user_name }}</p>
            <p class="card-header">Kitöltés dátuma: {{ item.date }}</p>
            <p class="card-header">User id: {{ item.user_name_id }} </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
  <h5>Tesztek:</h5>
      Viselkedéstípus:
        {% if item.vis01a %}
            <i class="fas fa-check fa-2x text-success"></i>
        {% else %}
            <i class="far fa-bell fa-lg text-warning"></i>
        {% endif %} 


{% for i in stressz_teszt %} //this is where I need the data of the specific user but I always get the datae of the logged in user
      Stressz-szint: 
        {% if i.stressz_v01 %}
            <i class="fas fa-check fa-2x text-success"></i>
        {% else %}
            <i class="far fa-bell fa-lg text-warning"></i> </td>
        {% endif %} 
{% endfor %} 
    </div> 
    </div> 

<a href="/mpa/{{ item.user_name_id }}" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Egyéni eredmények</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you probably want something like `request.user`.

Comment: No, this is the point. I don't need `request.user` but the  specific authenticated user.

Comment: what do you mean by specific authenticated user? `request.user` will give you the user for the current `request` and you may use `request.user.is_authenticated` to verify whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: I mean on specific user that has ID 7 or ID 1, etc.

Comment: are you looking for `request.user.id`?